# How to align my tree using forest?

Tags: forest, trees

I am trying to make a tree using forest. It is within minipage environment. But the tree does not aligns with the center of the page. Moreover I would like it if the subsequent levels too were centered around one vertical line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\makebox[\linewidth]{
\begin{forest}
for tree={
grow'=east,draw=black,parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, align=center,
edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
    (!u.parent anchor) -- +(10pt,0) |- 
    (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
},
}
[Microfabrication,
[Subtractive, 
[\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \noindent $\mu$ -EDM
  \item \noindent $\mu$ -ECM
  \item \noindent LBM
  \item \noindent EBM
  \item \noindent Micro-Cutting
  \item \noindent PCM
  \end{enumerate}}
  \end{minipage}]
  ]
  [Additive
  [\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Surface Coating
  \item Direct Writing
  \item Stereolithography
  \item Chemical \\ Deposition
  \item Polymer \\ Deposition
  \end{enumerate}}
  \end{minipage}]
  ]
  [Lithography Based
  [\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Photolithography
  \item LIGA
  \item Soft Lithography
  \item X-Ray \\ Lithography
  \end{enumerate}}
  \end{minipage}]
  ]
  [Hybrid
  [\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}{
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item  Surface Coating
  \item  Direct Writing
  \item  Stereolithography
  \item  Chemical Deposition
  \item  Polymer Deposition
  \end{enumerate}}
  \end{minipage}]
  ]
  ]
  \end{forest}}
  \captionof{figure}{Microfabrication Techniques}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{document}
```

Here is the output
[image: Output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dispensed with the `minipage` environment and I made it easier to handle. Also, I centered the titles and streched the boxes with the items.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=5pt,right=5pt,top=10pt,bottom=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{2mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
    child anchor=west,
    parent anchor=east,
    grow'=east, text centered,
    text width=5cm,
    draw,
    anchor=west,
    edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (.child anchor) -| +(-2pt,0) -- +(-8pt,0) |-
        (!u.parent anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
    }
    [\centering Microfabrication
        [{Subtractive}
            [{\begin{enumerate}
                \item $\mu$ -EDM
                \item $\mu$ -ECM
                \item LBM
                \item EBM
                \item Micro-Cutting
                \item PCM
            \end{enumerate}}\vs
        ]
    ]
    [Additive
            [{\begin{enumerate}
                \item Surface Coating
                \item Direct Writing
                \item Stereolithography
                \item Chemical Deposition
                \item Polymer Deposition
            \end{enumerate}}\vs
        ]
    ] 
    [Lithography Based
            [{\begin{enumerate}
                \item Photolithography
                \item LIGA
                \item Soft Lithography
                \item X-Ray Lithography
            \end{enumerate}}\vs
        ]
    ]
    [Hybrid
            [{\begin{enumerate}
                \item  Surface Coating
                \item  Direct Writing
                \item  Stereolithography
                \item  Chemical Deposition
                \item  Polymer Deposition
            \end{enumerate}}\vs
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}}
\caption{Microfabrication Techniques}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ThanX! This worked great. Though I let go of the {geometry} package as it was clashing with something. But, would this tree be floating or fixed on the page?

Comment: Yes, you can get rid of `geometry` package in preamble. I have to say, it was only for the printing of the image, I forgot to remove it. You do not need to use that since it would compromise the rest of the document.

Answer (score 4):

like this?

[image]

nodes with lists are horizontally aligned with `forest` option `tier/.pgfmath=level()`. for list is employed `enumitem` package. instead `minipage` in nodes with lists is used `forest` option `where n children=0{text width=4cm}{},`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setlist{nosep, leftmargin=*, before= \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}}
    \centering
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw=black,
    where n children=0{text width=4cm}{},   % <---
    grow'=0,
    l sep=2em,                  
    forked edge,
    fork sep=1em,                           % <---
    anchor=west,
    tier/.pgfmath=level(),                  % <---
    },
[Microfabrication
 [Subtractive
  [\begin{enumerate}                        % no minipage
    \item $\mu$ -EDM
    \item $\mu$ -ECM
    \item LBM
    \item EBM
    \item Micro-Cutting
    \item PCM
   \end{enumerate}]
  ]
 [Additive
  [\begin{enumerate}
    \item Surface Coating
    \item Direct Writing
    \item Stereolithography
    \item Chemical Deposition
    \item Polymer Deposition
   \end{enumerate}]
  ]
 [Lithography Based
  [\begin{enumerate}
    \item Photolithography
    \item LIGA
    \item Soft Lithography
    \item X-Ray Lithography
   \end{enumerate}]
  ]
  [Hybrid
  [\begin{enumerate}
    \item  Surface Coating
    \item  Direct Writing
    \item  Stereolithography
    \item  Chemical Deposition
    \item  Polymer Deposition
   \end{enumerate}]
   ]
 ]
\end{forest}
  \caption{Microfabrication Techniques}
  \label{fig:forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**addendum (1):** 
if you more like to have equal width of all nodes in `forest`, then for `for tree` options use the following:

```
  for tree={
    draw=black,
    text width=38mm,                         % <---
    text centered,                           % <---
    grow'=0,
    l sep=2em,
    forked edge,
    fork sep=1em,                           
    anchor=west,
    },
```

and you will obtain:

[image]

in comparison with your *mwe* i put image in float environment `figure` with option `[ht]` which ensure that diagram will be in text where is inserted, if on page is enough place for it or in opposite case on the top of the next page.

**addendum (2):**

one more example (just for exercise). with `for tree` options:

```
  for tree={
    draw=black,
    where n children=1{text width=2cm, text centered}{},  % <---
    where n children=0{text width=4cm}{},                 % <---
    grow'=0,
    l sep=2em,
    forked edge,
    fork sep=1em,
    anchor=west,
    },
```

you will obtain:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This too would work good, but Cragfelt's output looks a bit better.

Comment: @Siddharth, i'm just curious: in which sense cragfelt's answer looks better? i made add an option with  equal width nodes in diagram. is this what you looking for?

Comment: Well, yes nodes with equal width do look better. So now your output is similar to his. But I am new to Latex, so I am looking for simplistic solutions. His solution seemed more simplistic to me. It is very much possible that your code could be better, but I am no judge of that. Thanks.

Comment: @Siddharth, in your question you not mentioned, that you like to have equal width of nodes. and people has different taste ... since you select `forest`, which is very powerful but demanding package, i expect, that you are familiar with it or at least on the way to learn more about it. i show you some possibilities how to use it (i still learn it). if you more prefer Cragfelt answer, than please accept it.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to learn forest and I also do accept I hadn't mentioned that I need equal width nodes.