# Make a forest horizontal

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

i want to make a vertical forest and align the green boxes. From [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402545/how-to-align-my-tree-using-forest) i got a nice `for tree=` but i actually dont understand what is happening here.

At the moment i have this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=5pt,right=5pt,top=10pt,bottom=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{2mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%    
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        child anchor=west, % connection-point ->north
        parent anchor=east, % connection-point ->south
        grow'=east, text centered, %grow down -> south
        text width=5cm, 
        draw, %draw the tree
        anchor=west, % ?
        edge path={ % actually dont understand here anything
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (.child anchor) -| +(-2pt,0) -- +(-8pt,0) |-
            (!u.parent anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
        }
    }
        [level0
            [level1
                [level2-1, bottom color=green!20
                    [level3-1]
                    [level3-2]
                    ]
                [level2-2, bottom color=green!20
                    [level3-3]
                    [level3-4]
                    ]
                ]
            [level2-3, bottom color=green!20
                [loooooooong -level3-5]
                [loooooooong -level3-6]
                ]
        ] 
    \end{forest}}
\captionof{figure}{myname}
\label{fig:stil_ml}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With the cahnges in the code commands i got this.

[image]

But it dont look so pretty.

What i finally want is this here.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand your edited question, than you looking for something like this:

**Edit:**
Considered is edited answer:

[image]

**Edit:**
corrected are anchors and added is `tier/.option=level`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=5pt,right=5pt,top=10pt,bottom=10pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}      % <--- added option edges
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
% nodes
        text centered, 
        text width=24mm,
        minimum height=9mm,
        font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.9}\selectfont,
        draw, 
% tree
        grow' = south,            % <--- grow down -> south
       anchor = north,            % <--- new
        forked edge,              % <--- new
        l sep = 6mm,
        s sep = 2mm,
     fork sep = 3mm,              % <--- new
         edge = {draw, semithick},% <--- changed
  where level = {2}{top color=green!50!black, bottom color=green!20}
                    {},
tier/.option = level
            }% end of tree
[level0
    [level1
        [level2-1, 
            [level3-1]
            [level3-2]
            ]
        [level2-2, 
            [level3-3]
            [level3-4]
            ]
        ]
    [,coordinate
        [level2-3 
            [loooooooong -level3-5]
            [loooooooong -level3-6]
        ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\caption{myname}                 % <--- changed
\label{fig:stil_ml}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Changes in above MWE in comparison to yours are marked with `% <--- ...`. Since tree is quite wide I reduce width of nodes shapes to 24 mm and allow two line of nodes contents where is necessary, minimal height is selected so, that the all nodes have the same height. Also use `footnotesize` for font size.

Comment: aaah yes :D but two things are missing. i want to all the green boxes, level2 align and the level3 among themselves. for example
level2-2 ->level3-3 ->level3-4

Comment: No, nothing is missed in my answer :-) This is your new demand. Please edit your question and clearly describe, how your tree should look.

Comment: hej zarko its in the first sentence :D :P but i added the question. ty for your advice

Comment: @credenco, first setence is not very clear ... I edit my answer, please see, if now the tree is as you like to have.

Comment: yes, thats it. thanks for your help